# nhibernate group by join query

Tags: nhibernate, join, group-by, aggregate-functions, queryover

I have the following entities:

```
public class Shift
{
    public virtual int ShiftId { get; set; }
    public virtual string ShiftDesc { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<ShiftHistory> ShiftHistory { get; set; }
}

public class ShiftHistory
{
    public virtual System.DateTime ShiftStartLocal { get; set; }
    public virtual System.DateTime ShiftEndLocal { get; set; }

    public virtual Zone Zone { get; set; }
    public virtual Shift Shift { get; set; }

    public virtual int RowId { get; set; }
}

public class Zone
{
    public virtual int EntId { get; set; }
    public virtual string EntName { get; set; }
}
```

A shift is a shift definition, zone is a place where people work and shift history is history data of when a shift was run at a zone.

What I need is to **get the last time a shift was run for all zones**.

/* EDIT: Sorry, I was vague. Every shift can have a history at multiple zones. What I need is the latest history irrespective of the zone, for each shift, in any NH query type. */

But this is not so simple, at least not for me now, and I've spend too much time on this, and have finally resorted to doing a sql query:

```
public class GetAllShiftSchedules : AbstractQueryObject<IList<ShiftScheduleResult>>
{
    public override IList<ShiftScheduleResult> GetResult()
    {   
        //use distinct because of the zones - if a shift is run at multiple zones, it ends at the same time, no? :)
        var sql =
            @"
            select distinct
                sh.ShiftId, s.ShiftDesc, sh.ShiftStartLocal, sh_inner.LatestEndTimeLocal
                from ShiftHistory sh
                  inner join Shift s on s.ShiftId = sh.ShiftId
                  inner join 
                  (
                    select ShiftId, max(ShiftEndLocal) as LatestEndTimeLocal from ShiftHistory group by ShiftId
                  )  
                   sh_inner on sh_inner.ShiftId = sh.ShiftId and sh_inner.LatestEndTimeLocal = sh.ShiftEndLocal
            ";

        var res = this.Session.CreateSQLQuery(sql).List().OfType<object[]>().Select(p => new ShiftScheduleResult(p)).ToList();

        return res;
    }
}

public class ShiftScheduleResult
{
    public int ShiftId { get; private set; }
    public string ShiftDesc { get; private set; }
    public DateTime LastShiftStartLocal { get; private set; }
    public DateTime LastShiftEndLocal { get; private set; }

    internal ShiftScheduleResult(object[] data)
    {
        this.ShiftId = (int)data[0];
        this.ShiftDesc = (string)data[1];
        this.LastShiftStartLocal = (DateTime)data[2];
        this.LastShiftEndLocal = (DateTime)data[3];
    }
}
```

The closest I got was having:

```
        var innerSubquery =
            QueryOver.Of<ShiftHistory>()
                .Select(
                    Projections.Group<ShiftHistory>(e => e.Shift),
                    Projections.Max<ShiftHistory>(e => e.ShiftEndLocal)); 

        IList<Shift> shifts =
            this.Session.QueryOver<Shift>()
                .JoinQueryOver<ShiftHistory>(p => p.ShiftHistory)
                .Where(Subqueries.WhereProperty<ShiftHistory>(p => p.ShiftEndLocal).Eq(innerSubquery)).List();
```

Which generated the following sql:

```
SELECT
...
 FROM
  Shift this_
   inner join ShiftHistory shifthisto1_ on this_.ShiftId=shifthisto1_.ShiftId
 WHERE
  shifthisto1_.ShiftEndLocal = 
  (
  SELECT this_0_.ShiftId as y0_, max(this_0_.ShiftEndLocal) as y1_ FROM ShiftHistory this_0_ GROUP BY this_0_.ShiftId
  )
```

Which of course fails because the group by select returns multiple values and we can't compare this to ShEndLoc.
This would actually work for me, if I could get the grouping projection to return only the max date. However, to make it complete, we should also be able to compare by shift id.

I am fine with returning the DTO but having an actual shift or a shift history included would be cool.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
        var list = 
            this.Session.Query<Shift>().Select(
                p => new
                {
                    Shift = p,
                    LastShiftHistory =
                        this.Session.Query<ShiftHistory>()
                            .Where(sh => sh.Shift == p)
                            .OrderByDescending(sh => sh.ShiftEndLocal)
                            .Select(sh => sh)
                            .FirstOrDefault()
                })
                .ToList();
```

should work. It would be better though to project to a DTO, since the subquery will lazy load.

Comment: Thanks. I gained imagination ;) I will test tomorrow.

Comment: Well, I edited your answer to reflect my requirements. But it does not work. It generates this sql: `select
 shift0_.ShiftId as col_0_0_,
 (
 select TOP (1) shifthisto1_.EntId, shifthisto1_.ShiftStartLocal
 from ShiftHistory shifthisto1_, Shift shift2_
 where shifthisto1_.ShiftId=shift2_.ShiftId and shifthisto1_.ShiftId=shift0_.ShiftId 
 order by shifthisto1_.ShiftEndLocal desc
 )  as col_1_0_,
 shift0_.ShiftId as shift1_20_,
 shift0_.ShiftDesc as shift2_20_
from Shift shift0_ `. It breaks of course.

Comment: The sql it is aiming for is something like:  `select *
  from Shift s
   inner join
    (
 select top 1 * from ShiftHistory sh where sh.ShiftId = s.ShiftId order by sh.ShiftEndLocal
 )
 sh on sh.ShiftId = s.ShiftId` .. however this sql is impossible because we cannot reference the outer s in the inner select.

Comment: What I tried was to have: `var list = this.Session.QueryOver<Shift>(() => shiftAlias).JoinAlias(() => shiftAlias.ShiftHistory, () => shiftHistoryAlias).Where(() => shiftAlias.ShiftId == shiftHistoryAlias.Shift.ShiftId).OrderBy(() => shiftHistoryAlias.ShiftEndLocal).Desc().Take(1).List();` .. which generates the equivalent of the sql in my previous comment - but without the where condition in the nested select, so it naturally returns only one row.. :\  .. Thanks for reading

Comment: Is ShiftHistory mapped as a component?

Comment: No. It is mapped as: `Bag<ShiftHistory>(x => x.ShiftHistory, colmap =>  { colmap.Key(x => x.Column("ShiftId"));  }, map => { map.OneToMany(x => x.Class(typeof(ShiftHistory))); });`. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Also, if that was how you wanted your query, the inner this.Session.Query<ShiftHistory>() can be replaced by p.ShiftHistory


I have a unit test with exactly your classes, and it works like a charm.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23817/discussion-between-gunteman-and-h-alex)

Comment: Thank you gunteman for your time. Composite keys on my end.. very good catch;)

Comment: Dude, this answer was blessing to me today!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work... Your result is annonymous type because of combination of caluses form different classes...

```
   public class QueryPlace()
    {
        List<ShiftHistory> ShiftHistrys = new List<ShiftHistory>();
        List<Shift> Shifts = new List<Shift>();
        List<Zone> Zones = new List<Zone>();

        public object MakeQuery()
        {
            var mshift = (from r in (from sh in session.Query<ShiftHistory>() from sf in session.Query<Shift>() where sh.Shift == sf
                         select new{sh.ShiftStartLocal, sh.ShiftEndLocal, sf.ShiftId, sf.ShiftHistory}) group r by r.ShiftId into g
                        select new {ShiftStartLocal = g.Max(s => s.ShiftStartLocal), ShiftEndLocal = g.Max(s => s.ShiftEndLocal), ShiftId = g.Key}).FirstOrDefault();

            return mshift;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It does not work. NH generates the -not supported- exception when executing.

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness, because this db of mine uses composite id's I wasn't able to get the full query gunteman provided.

What I ended up having is my original query, written in NH:

```
        var list =

        this.Session.Query<Shift>()
            .Select(
                p => 
                new ShiftScheduleResult()
                {
                    ShiftId =  p.ShiftId,
                    ShiftDesc = p.ShiftDesc,
                    LastShiftStartLocal
                        = p.ShiftHistory
                            .OrderByDescending(sh => sh.ShiftEndLocal)
                            .Select(x => x.ShiftStartLocal)
                            .FirstOrDefault(),
                    LastShiftEndLocal
                        = p.ShiftHistory
                            .OrderByDescending(sh => sh.ShiftEndLocal)
                            .Select(x => x.ShiftEndLocal)
                            .FirstOrDefault()
                })
            .ToList();
```

I believe that also Zoran's query would work.
Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score -1):

When the DB scheme combined with the business needs result in complicated queries, changing the DB scheme could be better.
By way of example, adding an "active" flag on your ShiftHistory, or adding a foreign key in your Shift on the last ShiftHistory.
Of course this could be considered as some "de-normalization", with possibility of having incoherent data in DB (more than one active history for the same Shift, or a "Last shift" foreign key not pointing on the real last one).
But would handling those risks cost you more than having a complicated query to maintain ? It is a trade-off to consider I think.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The thing is, I don't think this is a very complex query, it's just that I don't know how to write it. It is I think a rather common query, that I would like to know from an academic point of view. There is bound to be a scenario when I will need it. On a different note, this db is frozen and we are not allowed to modify it.